# How to get the UI Element "XPath" in UIView in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm new to Objective C and have a requirement to get the UIElement xpath in UIView. Any idea can help me))

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the xpath finder chrome extension?

Comment: I should not use any additional libraries, only the ones related to the UIKit for iOS apps (UIView, etc.)